# Is there a way to perform a negative search mask to forfiles?

Tags: batch-file, forfiles

I know how to utilize search masks in the forfiles command to target files of a particular extension, but I am working with a case where I want to avoid a particular extension and catch everything else.

Is there an easy way to achieve this with the forfiles command or will I need to write a custom for loop to handle this process? I am not looking to run a command like below which would force me to define my search masks before hand.

```
for %G in (.txt, .edi, .csv) do forfiles -p "C:abc\del" -s -m *%G -d -10 -c "cmd /c echo @path"
```

My use case is removing all files that are not encrypted from a directory recursively based on a single extension. This would be my negative value.

Comment: Why can you not just use, `... "cmd /c if not @ext == "yourext" echo @path"`! Or use `For /F "Delims=" %G In ('Dir /A-D^|FindStr /VE "your extensionlist"')Do...`

Comment: Ah I didnt think of that... I suppose I can always grab everything in all cases and just filter after the fact (like your first example).

Comment: @Compo That solution works enough for me. Do you mind creating that as an answer and ill close this out?

Comment: Just bear in mind that for every single file found in the `for` loop a new cmd.exe instance is being opened. It would be more efficient to filter in the `for` parentheses, then in the `do` command, then in the `forfiles`... Creating an answer, just for changing your standard `for` to a `for /f`, or to an a simple `if not` command hardly warrants the effort.

Comment: I stated that as you answered the question I was asking regarding how to apply a negative case to filter content from forfiles itself... Utilizing cmd /c to apply a filter after the fact is a logical approach that addresses the issue. Is this a question that you feel doesnt need to be asked?

Comment: As long as you're informed and happy with any deficiencies in using `Forfiles` like that, then there's absolutely nothing wrong with you asking or using a solution based upon it.

Comment: My particular use case will have a max of 20 files. If encryption fails for any files Im running this command as a precaution. Thanks for the information on the deficiencies though. Ill bear that in mind when working with larger sets of files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Compo's comments to my question, an approach to applying a negative search mask to the forfiles command would be to add a filter to the cmd implementation after the fact like so:

`forfiles /P %localDir% /S /M *.* /C "cmd /c if not @EXT == %ignoredExtension% echo @PATH`

However, @Compo raised a valid concern that this implementation would cause a new cmd.exe instance to be opened for every file found. In instances where the file count is fixed or known to be constant this may be a decent approach, but a more efficient alternative that is able to be scaled would be to create a for loop manually that applies this filter at the for loop instance before making the call to the do operations like so:

`For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('dir /A-D^|FindStr /VE %ignoredExtensions%')Do @echo %%G`

Comment: Just remember that the `ForFiles` variables, in this case `@EXT`, is a doublequoted string, so your comparator would need to include those. In `ForFiles` you can either escape the internal doublequotes, or replace them with their hex equivalent, `0x22`, and for safety the `FindStr` may also use case insensitivity, `/IVE` with either multiple `/C` instances or escaping the periods with a backslash, e.g. `\.ext1 \.ext2`.

Answer (score 1):

This batch file script command deletes everything older than 30 days if the filename does not end in PDF. It uses the 2003 version of `forfiles` in a Windows 7 cmd shell.

`forfiles` can not use reg exps, it only processes simple wildcards for masks. This is inefficient but ok for a small number of files.

````
for /f "delims=" %%X in ('dir /b %DIRNAME% ^|grep -vi pdf$') do forfiles /p %DIRNAME% /m "%%X" /d %DAYNUM% /c "cmd /c del @FILE" ```
````